# Can static global variables be optimised to be in the stack?

Tags: c, optimization

Assume I am declaring a static global variable in my C file:

```
static int my_var = 0;
```

And use it in only one function in that file:

```
static void func1(void)
{
    my_var = 1;
    my_var++;
    printf("my_var = %d\n", my_var);
}
```

The important thing here is that `my_var` is being overrwitten with a value (in this case 1 but could be a function or a calculation).
Assuming `my_var` will always start its life in `func1()` with a pre determined value which is not dependent on "last" call to `func1()`, can the compiler notice that and optimise the variable to be stored in the stack?

You must be asking yourself, why then don't just I use a local variable instead.
You are correct to ask but this a common mistake new C developers at my work do and I wanted to know if the compiler can optimise this paths as you can see the dependence graph of `my_var` and the decision shouldn't be that problematic.

Comment: I think hiring better developers should be your concern in this matter. Or maybe introducing a code review process, so it's not the tool chain that's tasked with handling this.

Comment: Yep, this is definitely an example of the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) applied to software engineering management.

Comment: Where is management digging up such coders?

Comment: I agree with you and I prefer not to dwell into this, but this what happens when code development is not the main goal of your team which is in this case HW validation.
We do have code reviews I personally hold as well but I can't be accountable to every piece of code of 30 developers :)

Comment: @AviramR If you have 30 developers who are contributing code at a rate faster than you can review, then you need support in reviewing the code.  Is there no one else on your project that you would deem capable of supporting you in this task?

Comment: @Ironcache, I understand this is an XY problem.
I am not trying to ask for an answer for the wider question as I also think it is not relevant to stackoverflow but to business as you said.
I was specifically interested in the outcome of such an example in terms of compilation as I am always interested in optimizations and compilation related issues which I face day by day at my work.

Comment: @AviramR Fair enough.  Though, when evaluating the usefulness of a question on SO, we make considerations for both the individual who asked the question, as well as any future individuals who may visit upon the question in a similar situation.  It is not personal; my commentary is how I would proceed about this if I was in the position outlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only that, but gcc will completely eliminate the variable altogether. https://godbolt.org/g/x947ck

```
.LC0:
  .string "my_var = %d\n"
func1():
  mov esi, 2
  mov edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
  xor eax, eax
  jmp printf
```

Notice how it has calculated that `my_var` is always 2, and doesn't allocate memory for the variable at all.

Comment: You're assuming that the code causing problems is as simple as the example.  If the only use of the variable in question is in the one function, the problem wouldn't appear.

Comment: @C_Elegans.: No need to apologize..Cool. All the best.

Comment: Thanks C_Elegans.
My intention was to compile with optimizer if that wasn't clear.
I would add that the fact that another function can have unrelated side effects shouldn't change the answer.
`my_var = func2();`
Assuming func2() doesn't touch my_var should still be relevant to the discussion.
I stated that my_var will be used in only one function which is `func1()`.
Of course `func1()` code can be very complex but it will still be the only user of `my_var`.

Comment: I am happy to learn gcc (we use clang) is capable of such optimizations, however in code reviews I always adhere to the tradeoffs of stack vs. global variables as I work in an embedded environment.

Answer (score 4):

**Fix the engineers, not the software.**

Given the nature of this question, I didn't want the only answers attached to it being code-related fixes to (what seems to be) a much broader problem.

As I mentioned in the comments of the question, I believe this is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem); what I mean by this is that the question is asking about how to optimize a particular solution, but should be asking about how best to handle the problem (though, such a question would likely end up getting flagged as opinion-based or off-topic, which begs the question as to if this really was the right way to ask the question on SO, but that's a tangent).

On point, the solution to the problem of engineering staff implementing sub-optimal solutions should not be to handle these sub-optimal implementations as gracefully as possible.  There are really only two good ways to handle this problem:

- **Refinement**: Educate your engineers.  Teach them why their implementations are sub-optimal, and what a more optimal approach would be.
- **Replacement**: Substitute engineers who implement sub-optimal solutions with engineers who implement optimal ones.

Obviously, attempting to educate should be the first step here.  In most companies now, this would exist in the form code reviews, allowing for discussion of potential pitfalls, and collaboration on better methods of tackling them.  But there are numerous techniques that can be applied here, and it's a matter of finding what has the most effective results for your team.

Answer (score -4):

> can the compiler notice that and optimise the variable to be stored in the stack?

No.

Doing so would violate the semantic requirements of the C standard.  There's no way to tell the compiler that the overriding of values isn't supposed to affect other independent accesses to the variable.  Removing that side effect of the function calls would therefore violate the C standard.

If you want a variable local to a function, use a variable local to a function.  You're trying to build a house using "carpenters" who don't know what wood is.

Comment: OP explicitly said that such variable is used only in that function, so there's no such a thing as independent access barring multithread; given that that variable is not atomic and there's no read or write barrier in that function, the compiler is allowed to eliminate it completely without altering the observable behavior of the program.

Comment: @MatteoItalia The compiler can optimize away the variable entirely - it can't move it to the stack.  That's a distinct difference.

Comment: Whether that `1` or `2` gets put into a register or on the stack is irrelevant - the compiler is authorized to put it wherever it likes most as long as the observable behavior is the same. If that variable weren't an `int` but something bigger and/or the optimizer was under register pressure, it would probably be moved on the stack.

Comment: @MatteoItalia If the question completely describes the problem, there is no problem, so why the question?  As noted in the comments above, this really looks like an XY problem.  In that case, the proposed "optimization" is not a solution and the effects of such a change need to be made clear:  moving the variable to the stack changes its lifetime and therefore the semantics of the program.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: The semantics of the program consist solely of the observable behavior specified by the C standard. All descriptions of lifetime and other properties are only parts of an abstract model. An implementation is not required to implement the abstract model in any aspect other than that the specified observable behavior is produced.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Is a barrier relevant here?
If the observability of the usage of the variable in question is in a way such that it is only used in that specific function, I don't see how a barrier should change the outcome.

Comment: @AviramR: what if that single function gets invoked by multiple threads? If there are read/write barriers between the variable assignment and its usage one thread potentially *has* to influence the other one through that variable.

Comment: That being said, as others remarked above, you shouldn't be worried about the performance implications of this toy case, you should be worried about the fact that your developers write code that sucks. If a developer doesn't understand how to use locals you shouldn't hope that his code runs fast, but that it works at all.